# Regularity of Parabolic PDE's

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, parabolic-pde

In Evans' PDE Book, in the first Theorem of regularity of parabolic PDE's there consider the case where the coefficients  $a^{ij},b^i,c$ of the uniformly parabolic operator (divergent form) $L$ coefficients are all smooth and don't depend on the time parameter $t$. Let $\{w_n\}$ be a basis of orthonormal eigenvectors of the operator $\Delta$. Finally, let $\{u_m\}$ be the sequence of Galerkin approximations for the equation
$$
\begin{cases}
\mathbf{u}_t + L \mathbf{u}= \mathbf{f} &\text{ in } U\times [0,T] \\
\mathbf{u} = 0 &\text{ in } \partial U \times [0,T]\\
\mathbf{u}(0) = g &\text{ in } U
\end{cases} 
$$ 
where $\mathbf{f} \in H^{1}(0,T; L^2(U)) $, $g \in H^1_0(U)\cap H^2(U) $ and $U$ is a open, bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^N $ with smooth boudary.

In p. 363 (of the first edition), Evans points out
$$
(I) \qquad
\|\mathbf{u}^\prime_{m}(0) \| \le C (\|\mathbf{f} \|_{H^{1}(0,T; L^2(U))} +
\|\mathbf{u}(0) \|_{H^2(U)})
$$
(he actually claims something the term in the LHR plus something else is smaller than the RHS, so the term $\|\mathbf{f} \|_{H^{1}(0,T; L^2(U))}$ might not be required) which he justifies referring to the equation 
$$
(II)\qquad (\mathbf{u}^\prime_{m},w_k) + B[\mathbf{u}_m,w_k ]= (\mathbf{f},w_k).
$$

Well, my attempt is to multiply $(II)$ by the right coefficients in both sides and evaluate at $0$ (which at this point I don't know how to justify that $(II)$ holds, as the equation only holds almost surely) to get
$$
\|\mathbf{u}^\prime_{m}(0)\|^2_{L^2(U)} + B[\mathbf{u}_m,\mathbf{u}^\prime_m ]= (\mathbf{f},\mathbf{u}^\prime_m).
$$
So I imagine the first step is to use the bounds of the coefficients of $L$ to get
$$
(III) \qquad |B[\mathbf{u}_m(0),\mathbf{u}^\prime_m (0)]|\le
C(\|\mathbf{u}_m(0)\|^2_{H^1_0(U)}+ \|\mathbf{u}^\prime_m(0) \|^2_{H^1_0(U)})
$$
and 
$$
(IV) \qquad
|(\mathbf{f}(0),\mathbf{u}^\prime_m(0))|\le
C(\|\mathbf{f}(0)\|^2_{L^2(U)}+ \|\mathbf{u}^\prime_m(0) \|^2_{L^2(U)})
$$

However, the fact that $(III)$ the RHS depends on $ \|\mathbf{u}^\prime_m(0) \|^2_{H^1_0(U)}$ and not on $ \|\mathbf{u}^\prime_m(0) \|^2_{L^2(U)}$ is rather annoying, as if it was the case, I could just use $\varepsilon$-Cauchy to get the desired result. Unfortunately, the Poincaré Inequality would point to the 'wrong' side of what I want. Moreover, as I said, I don't know how to justify that $(II)$ holds at $t=0$. How could I solve those problems?

Comment: Instead of (III) and (IV), use the bound $B[u,v]\leq C\|u\|_{H^1_0} \|v\|_{H^1_0}$ and use Cauchy-Schwarz in (IV). Then you can divide both sides by $\|u_m'(0)\|$ to get the estimate.

Comment: Could you develop a bit further? The problem for me is that the inequality you suggested $B[u(0),u^\prime (0)]\le C \|u(0)\|_{H^1_0}  \|u_m^\prime(0)\|_{H^1_0} $. On the other hand Cauchy-Schwarz gets  $|(\mathbf{f}(0),u_m^\prime(0))|\le
C(\|f(0)\|^2_{L^2} \|u_m^\prime(0) \|^2_{L^2}). 
$ Then you would have 
$\|u^\prime_m(0)\|^2_{L^2} \le \|f(0)\|_{L^2} \|u^\prime_m(0)\|_{L^2} +  C \|u_m(0)\|_{H^1_0}  \|u_m^\prime(0)\|_{H^1_0}$. So if divide by either $ \|u_m^\prime(0)\|_{H^1_0} $ or $ \|u_m^\prime(0)\|_{L^2}$  you don't really get the expected result.

Comment: No, Cauchy Schwarz gives $|(u,v)|\leq \|u\| \|v\|$.

Comment: Sorry, that I was me being lazy and copying from the question without  correcting it. In any case, in the last inequality of my previous comment, I had applied  CS properly, so how should I proceed?

Comment: It should work if you use $B[u_m,u_m']=(Lu_m,u_m')\leq C\|u_m\|_{H^2}\|u_m'\|_{L^2}$.